# Mongodb 4.0.4 installation error in Linux

Tags: linux, mongodb

I am using 16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux (LINUX Mint)

I followed [offical documentation][1], but end up in errors.

installation using LATEST VERSION OF MongoDB

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Errors

```
Package mongodb-org is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mongodb-org' has no installation candidate
```

Installation using Specific release of Mongodb

```
$sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.0.4 mongodb-org-server=4.0.4 mongodb-org-shell=4.0.4 mongodb-org-mongos=4.0.4 mongodb-org-tools=4.0.4
```

Error

```
E: Version '4.0.4' for 'mongodb-org' was not found
E: Version '4.0.4' for 'mongodb-org-server' was not found
E: Version '4.0.4' for 'mongodb-org-shell' was not found
E: Version '4.0.4' for 'mongodb-org-mongos' was not found
E: Version '4.0.4' for 'mongodb-org-tools' was not found
```

Note : the above installation is done after executing these codes

```
$sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
$echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
$sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Installation works in $ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb 4.0.4                  but here MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

sudo service mongod start
```

Comment: The same error exists : E: Package 'mongodb-org' has no installation candidate at $ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org

Comment: How can i do it in a single script and on a double click it has to run all the commands

Answer (score 0):

```
$sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
$echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
$sudo apt-get update
```

Note that you have `ubuntu trusty` in the .list file, but you stated that you are running `Ubuntu 16.04`. The installation documentation has tabs for the supported Ubuntu releases. For example, clicking on the tab for Ubuntu 16.04 provides the following:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
```

You may need to remove the old `.list` file and start from scratch to remove any potential conflicts. So `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list`.

Then repeat the installation steps, making sure to select the correct tab for your Ubuntu version. You can `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list` to double check everything matches up.

I've validated our installation instructions on Ubuntu 16.04 in VM as recently as last week, so we should be able to get you up and running here.

Answer (score 0):

You state:

```
I am using 16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP i686 athlon **i686** GNU/Linux (LINUX Mint)
```

Your system is **32bit**.

Yet you are trying to install **amd64 (64bit)** sources/packages:

```
$echo "deb [ **arch=amd64** ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list
```

This won't work.

**Solution: Install Ubuntu 64bit.**